# Sequelize - sync many-to-many

Tags: node.js, laravel, express, sequelize.js

Currently with Sequelize, if I post up a new array of IDs for a many-to-many relationship, I need to loop through all existing relations to see which ones to remove, which ones to add etc etc. It's all really manual.

In Laravel, I can just use `->sync($relationIds)` and it'll update all of an entity's relations to match the array of IDs I pass in.

Does Sequelize have something like this?

For example say my `Order` has a many-to-many with `MenuItem`.
Can I pass in `menuItemIds` (being `[23,51,2,10]`), and have it create new relations if they don't exist, and remove ones that aren't in the array, without me having to do all this logic myself?